# actorSelection with relative path messages going to dead letters

Tags: java, akka, actor

I have created an ActorSystem a synopsis of my system is

```
akka://JL/user/store/meatProcessor
akka://JL/user/store/Server/
```

The store contructor looks like this

```
.....
public Store(){
    server = this.getContext().actorOf(
            Props.create(Server.class)
            .withDispatcher("my-thread-pool-dispatcher")
            .withRouter(new RoundRobinPool(lowerBound)
            .withResizer(resizer)),
            "Server");
....
meatProcessor = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(meatProcessor.class)
                            .withRouter(new RoundRobinPool(lowerBound)
                            .withResizer(resizer)),
            "meatProcessor");
......}
```

So if "store" creates these two actors it should be their parent right?

When I am in in the meatProcessor actor

I try to send a message to the Server with the following

```
getContext().actorSelection("../Server").tell(new SomeMsg(), getSelf());
```

My messages are sent to dead letters.

But it works when I use the Absolute path of

```
getContext().actorSelection("user/store/Server").tell(new SomeMsg(), getSelf());
```

Can anyone tell me why ".." does not work?

Comment: This question is too specific (your particular program) and at the same time not well enough specified (does not contain enough information to answer it); please consider reworking or removing it.

Comment: Is it possible that your meatProcessor actor is not actually a sibling to the `Server` actor like you think it is?  That would certainly result in the behavior you are seeing where the relative path does not work but the absolute path does.

Comment: I edited my original post and added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug when using a router.

I got it to work by doing this

```
getContext().actorSelection("../../Server").tell(new SomeMsg(), getSelf());
```